# How to integrate $\sec^3 x \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indefinite integral of secant cubed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154900/indefinite-integral-of-secant-cubed)

How to integrate $\sec^3 x \, dx$?
Can someone please give a method, I tried separating $\sec^3 x$ as $\sec x(\sec^2 x)$ then applying by-parts method but it didn't yield anything useful

Comment: Please show the rest of your work so we can help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$$\sec^3(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^3(x)}=\frac{\cos(x)}{(1-\sin^2(x))^2} $$

$u=\sin(x)$.

Comment: Is this one your own or can something in the literature be cited?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well it is my idea, I also calculate $\int \sec(x)dx$ this way.... BUT, the theory of trig integrals says that if $\cos(x)$ appears at an odd power, then the sub $u=\sin(x)$ works. Typically people use this for products, but it also works for ratios....So in some sense it is a pretty standard method, is just that people in general fail to realize that it can be applied to more general settings...

Answer (score 7):

There's a whole Wikipedia article about just this integral: [Integral of secant cubed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed).

You're mistaken to think that integration by parts doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

Use integration by parts; $u = \sec(x)$, $dv = \sec^2(x)\, dx$, $v = \tan(x)$ and $du = \sec(x)\tan(x)$. Now use the Pythagorean identity for $\tan$ and $\sec$.  You will solve for the $\int\sec^3(x)\, dx$.

Answer (score 2):

$\int \sec^3x \,dx=\int \sec x (\sec^2 x \, dx)$

Let $\tan x=t\implies \sec^2 x \,dx=dt$ and $\sec x=\sqrt{1+t^2}$ which changes our integral to $\int \sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt$ which is a standard integral which evaluates to $\frac{t\sqrt{1+t^2}}{2}+\frac{\log(t+\sqrt{1+t^2})}{2}$. Now back substitute $t=\tan x$ in answer