# Integration thought process

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Recently, a friend of mine asked me for the indefinite integral
$$F(x)=\int \sec^3(x)$$
Integrating by parts, letting $u=\sec(x), dv=\sec^2(x)$, we have
$$F(x)=\sec(x)\tan(x)-\int \sec(x)\tan^2(x)$$
But now:
$$G(x)=\int \sec(x)\tan^2(x)=\int \sec(x)(\sec^2(x)-1)=F(x)-\int\sec(x)$$
And finally(and somewhat magically) $\int\sec(x)=\ln(|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|)$, which gives us:
$$F(x)=\sec(x)\tan(x)-(F(x)-\ln(|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|)))$$
$$\implies F(x)=\frac{\sec(x)\tan(x)+\ln(|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|)}{2}$$

The last integral was written as a derivation excercise some weeks ago, so there is where my motivation comes from. But, is there a logical way to come up with it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154900/indefinite-integral-of-secant-cubed

Comment: @T.Bongers Thank you for the link. I was specifically asking for the thought process of $\int \sec(x)$, but I also found it in the related links of that post. Partial fractions was a method I dind't knew for integration! Do I close it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: Also be sure to check out the solution using the magical [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)!

Comment: This integral is also easy to remember, since its simply the arithmetic mean of the derivative of $\sec(x)$ and integral of $\sec(x)$...

Comment: @DavidH That promises to be the ultimate tool for trigonometric integration :D

Comment: @chubakueno It's an excellent ace to have up your sleeve. It'll also give you an edge over other students since calculus's classes sadly almost never mention it.

Comment: for integral of $\sec x$ just let $u = \sec x + \tan x$. I think this is easiest, however, I just pushed the magic back one level. So, is this really better than just knowing the antiderivative of $\sec x$ from memory? Maybe a little...